# ggplot plot x-axis transferred with log10 issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have lots of PDF distribution numbers (attached). Because normal way, I couldn't plot it. Then I used the log10 transfers x-axis. However, is there any way to still show original x-axis (not take a log10)?

```
ggplot(data = dist_cdf,aes(x= log10(num), y=pert_sales)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black") + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, 9), se = FALSE,
              span = 1.5, size=1.2, colour = "#FF3300", linetype = 1)
```

current figure is something like this:

[image]

Part of the data：

```
structure(list(num = 1:30, pert_sales = c(0.020194064, 0.020140418, 
0.014049199, 0.012375386, 0.008335432, 0.007140572, 0.006361819, 
0.006179615, 0.005034322, 0.004976598, 0.004922225, 0.004602446, 
0.004490266, 0.004264869, 0.0039289, 0.00387972, 0.003612034, 
0.00357951, 0.00337985, 0.00326423, 0.003048265, 0.002862149, 
0.002769482, 0.002764383, 0.002760949, 0.002760627, 0.002721623, 
0.002617593, 0.002405228, 0.002319419)), row.names = c(NA, 30L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You want to show both the log scaled X-axis and the unscaled X-axis?

Comment: Thanks. No, I just want the x-axis shown as the original one (unscaled). It seems that I cannot upload the data file here:-(

Comment: Take a look at the options in `?scale_x_continuous`

Comment: not work, it shows 1e+01, 1e+10... some strange things

Comment: Can you show an example of your data using dput(head(dist_cdf,30))?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: That's scientific notation `1e+` means `1 x 10^`, so: `1e+01 = 10`, `1e+02 = 100`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a log10 x axis it's much better to use `scale_x_log10()` than converting the number itself in the aes as if you add other aes or limits etc they will also be transformed, also gives you labels of the original data not of log10. To stop these being in scientific notation (1e+01, 1e+10 etc) you can use labels = comma from the scales library. So:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(data = dist_cdf,aes(x= num, y=pert_sales)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black")) + 
  scale_x_log10(labels = comma)+
          stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, 9), se = FALSE,span = 1.5,size=1.2,colour = "#FF3300",linetype = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this way. However, the x-axis is still not correct. What I mean "strange" is not about the scientific notation, but the x label's values are not right. The correct x-axis should be from 1-20,0000 but this way is from 1-100,000. I am confused what's happening. My code is right, but x labels show the real values of log10(x)...

Comment: Are you sure its not that the axis goes to 200,000 but that there is no break there? you could try manually adding it as a break if you need it i.e. `scale_x_log10(labels = comma, breaks = c(1*10^c(1:5),2e5))`